# Adding ctags for a 3rd party library

Tags: autocompletion, tags, ctags, plugin-you-complete-me

I would like to know how to generate ctags and find them with auto-complete plugins for new libraries that I install in order to 1) auto-complete for 3rd party library namespaces, classes, etc. and 2) not have my syntax checking plugin think I have undefined references. In order to generate tags for my own new projects, I use this command:

```
map <C-F12> :!ctags -R --sort=yes --c++-kinds=+pl --fields=+iaSl --extra=+q .<CR>
```

But how do I adapt this to new libraries in my system? I have tried going to a library's include directory, run the above command, and then set the ctag path to find the tags file, e.g.

```
:set tags+=/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/tags
```

But then it seems that the tags are not found. I use the YouCompleteMe and I have the collect_identifiers parameter set:

```
let g:ycm_collect_identifiers_from_tags_files = 1
```

How can I enable ctags to find them? I can using Exuberant Ctags 5.9 and VIM 7.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this to tell Vim to look recursively for `tags` files under `/usr/include/`:

```
set tags+=/usr/include/**/tags
```

For the generation part, I'm afraid you will still have to generate `tags` files manually for each new library… or write a shell script.

---

By the way, Vim comes with what it calls "include-search"; you will probably find the following help sections interesting:

```
:help include-search
:help definition-search
:help 'include'
:help 'define'
```

Comment: I added that to my .vimrc and didn't see a change. I also tried to start vim, enter ":set tags=/usr/include/***/tags" and ":set tags=/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/tags". Neither of those worked. I also changed the owner to my username since those tags are in /usr and I might need sudo to access them. I did ":echo tagfiles()" and I see the path to the library tag file, but still I can't auto-complete and I get undefined reference errors in Syntastic. I tried to add the path to a tag file in my /opt directory and that worked fine. Any ideas for why that would happen?

Comment: I am accepting the answer even though my problem still exists because I think my problem is not normal. As I said in my previous comment, when I did this for another library it worked fine so this would be the normal way of doing things.